# Bad normal smoothing around bevel after boolean

Tags: normals, bevel, boolean-modifier

I am trying to do a boolean difference between 2 cylinders. The boolean itself and cleaning up the mesh afterwards didn't pose any issue, however the shading looks pretty bad after applying a bevel (see below). It doesn't look like I have any overlapping geometry, it looks more like a normal smoothing issue, so I tried marking the outermost edges of the (destructive) bevel as sharp. This essentially fixes the shading but makes the bevel look very.. well sharp. Do I have to do a normals transfer to keep the bevel smooth while avoiding shading issues or is there an alternative ?

Here is a link to the file : https://we.tl/t-vqDEHDPSgE

[image: Mesh before bevel]
[image: Shading issues around the bevel.]
[image: After applying sharp edges. Shading is now great but the transition from the bevel to the surface itself looks a little too sharp to my taste.]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file so that we can give a try? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, sure, I edited and added a link to the file

Comment: Your result will always be a lot better if you spend a moment cleaning up the geo around the beveled edge. It doesn't have to be 100% quads or anything, but you want to give the bevel modifier a decent path to send the new edges it creates. if the perpendicular edges are going off at weird angles then it will cause issues like this. 

Watch this video here to see what I'm talking about. 
https://youtu.be/cBxxTR2Zgb4?t=164

Comment: Hello, I think this is it yes. I tried creating a quad "buffer zone" for the bevel and I don't have problems anymore. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should redo it with less vertices?

Boolean a 16 vertex cylinder with another one that is 90° rotated on Z:

[image]

Apply the *Boolean*, mirror, rework the topology a bit:

[image]

Bevel as much as needed:

[image]

Result with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]